# Filling Array with subsequent value

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

In my dataframe I will end up with a column that only has few non-nan values. I want to use the non-nan values as grouping variables for all preceding rows that do contain a NaN value. To simulate it, I made the following array:

```
count = np.array([np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,3,np.NaN,np.NaN,6,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,12])
count = Series(count)
```

For this array I was able to create a filling function

```
def pad_expsamp_time(array):
    sect = np.zeros(array.size) # create array filled with zeros
    inds = array.index[array.notnull()] # select the non-zero values
    rev_inds = inds[::-1] # sort high to low
    # fill array with value until index of value. Repeat for lower values. 
    for i in rev_inds: 
        sect[:i] = i
    return Series(sect)
```

This function works, when it can assume that the indices of the non-nan values is equal to the actual values. However, **how can I fill an array when the indices are not equal to the content?**

---

For example, what if array count is:

```
count = np.array([np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,1,np.NaN,np.NaN,2,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,3])
```

And the desired output is

```
count = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3]
```

It is possible that there are NaNs at the end of the array. I would like these to stay NaNs, so that the dataframe will ignore them.

```
count = np.array([np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,1,np.NaN,np.NaN,2,np.NaN,np.NaN,3,np.NaN,np.NaN]) 
# Will become:
count = np.array([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,np.nan,np.nan]
```

Comment: Could the last element be `NaN`?

Comment: @Divakar yes it could indeed

Comment: So, do you need it to filled with something? If so, what should we fill it with? Add a sample case maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can simply use pandas [bfill()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.bfill.html) method:

your sample:

```
In [89]: s = pd.Series(np.array([np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan]))

In [90]: s
Out[90]:
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     1.0
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     2.0
7     NaN
8     NaN
9     3.0
10    NaN
11    NaN
dtype: float64

In [91]: s.bfill()
Out[91]:
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     2.0
5     2.0
6     2.0
7     3.0
8     3.0
9     3.0
10    NaN
11    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Divakar's samples:

```
In [81]: s = pd.Series(array([ nan,  nan,  nan,   6.,  nan,  nan,   5.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan, nan,   2.]))

In [82]: s
Out[82]:
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     6.0
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     5.0
7     NaN
8     NaN
9     NaN
10    NaN
11    NaN
12    2.0
dtype: float64

In [83]: s.bfill()
Out[83]:
0     6.0
1     6.0
2     6.0
3     6.0
4     5.0
5     5.0
6     5.0
7     2.0
8     2.0
9     2.0
10    2.0
11    2.0
12    2.0
dtype: float64

In [84]: s = pd.Series(array([ nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,  nan,  nan,   2.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan, nan, 3.]))

In [85]: s.bfill()
Out[85]:
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     2.0
5     2.0
6     2.0
7     3.0
8     3.0
9     3.0
10    3.0
11    3.0
12    3.0
dtype: float64

In [86]: s = pd.Series(array([ nan, nan, nan, 1., nan, nan, 2., nan, nan, 3., nan, nan]))

In [87]: s.bfill()
Out[87]:
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     2.0
5     2.0
6     2.0
7     3.0
8     3.0
9     3.0
10    NaN
11    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: @Divakar, IMO it's pretty standard Pandas operation, so there is no magic there ;)

Comment: Wow? Really? All the trouble for nothing haha. If only I would have known earlier. Now I can also stop writing a forward fill function...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
# Append False at either sides of NaN mask as we try to find start &
# stop of each NaN interval by looking for rising and falling edges
mask = np.hstack((False,np.isnan(count),False))
start = np.flatnonzero(mask[1:] > mask[:-1])
stop = np.flatnonzero(mask[1:] < mask[:-1])
lens = stop - start

# Account for NaNs if any at the end of input that might throw off stop values
stop = stop.clip(max=count.size-1)

# Assign values
count[mask[1:-1]] = count[stop].repeat(lens)
```

Sample runs -

Case #1 :

```
In [103]: count
Out[103]: 
array([ nan,  nan,  nan,   6.,  nan,  nan,   5.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,   2.])

In [104]:  # Listed code ...

In [105]: count
Out[105]: array([ 6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.])
```

Case #2 :

```
In [118]: count
Out[118]: 
array([ nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,  nan,  nan,   2.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan,   3.])

In [119]:   # Listed code ...

In [120]: count
Out[120]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.])
```

Case #3 :

```
In [114]: count
Out[114]: 
array([ nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,  nan,  nan,   2.,  nan,  nan,   3.,  nan,
        nan])

In [115]:   # Listed code ...

In [116]: count
Out[116]: 
array([  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   2.,   2.,   2.,   3.,   3.,   3.,  nan,
        nan])
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!